# Android.mk and library project

Tags: java, android, android-source

I have an application and a shared library (composed of Java classes and resources).
I'm trying to compile my app directly in a ROM and I need to write the Android.mk.
However it's not working as expected.

Here are my two Android.mk:

Library:

`LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)`

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := SharedLibrary

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)

# additionally, build tests in sub-folders in a separate .apk
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

App:

`LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)`

```
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRAIRIES = SharedLibrary

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Pricing

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

# additionally, build tests in sub-folders in a separate .apk
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: I suppose you have your first `Android.mk` in your jni folder, correct ? I guess you would need `Application.mk` for your app, not another `Android.mk`

Comment: I'm not using jni, I just have 2 java projects (one is an app and the other one is the lib)

Comment: Could you please share the output of make (the related part) ?